# What serialization does WF 4.5 use with SQL

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I know that 3.5 used binary and I was hoping that 4.5 used something else or was flexible and allowed for plugging in different serializers.

Edit:

I'm looking for what it uses for serialization to the SQL during persistence.

Comment: Did you look in the database?  I'd wager it's xaml.

Answer (score 2):

I think it uses a binary serialization internally, but I'm not 100% sure. You can't replace the serialization (other than to indicate you want gzip encoding) unless you write your own instance store class.
However you can write a PersistenceParticipant which can add properties to the stored state (useful if you need to look up particular instances by some value e.g. customer number) or an IOPersistenceParticipant which can participate in the persistence transaction (useful if you need to store additional state outside the instance store but want the data to be consistent).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using straight WF or WF services. WF services have a couple serialization option. XML or data contract. you can find the details on MSDN.

[Configuring Serialization in a Workflow Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-serialization-in-a-workflow-service)

Comment: Thanks Todd but I wasn't specific enough. I've updated the original question to reflect that I wanted to know what kind of serialization WF uses for persistence. I believe your link is referring to what it uses across the wire. Also, your link didn't work for me, but this one did: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742829%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396